# Can extra transaction validation logic be implemented at orderer level?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

As i understand the function of orderer service is to  send transaction to peers in the order it was received with total-order delivery and reliability for consensus. As a developer can i add code to orderer service to perform extra validation check before it broadcast block to validating peers, like tx1 should always come before tx2 or performing some validation on basis of transaction payload.

Answer (score 0):

While extending current ordering service implementation doesn't sound a right approach to me, if you would like to add an additional validation policy you might probably consider eplore the possibility of leveraging pluggable ESCC or VSCC policies (endorsement, validation policies respectively).

Moreover you can bring your own ordering service and plug it instead of two currently available options as long as it conforms/implements with Deliver/Broadcast APIs.

```
message BroadcastResponse {
    common.Status status = 1;
}

message SeekNewest { }

message SeekOldest { }

message SeekSpecified {
    uint64 number = 1;
}

message SeekPosition {
    oneof Type {
        SeekNewest newest = 1;
        SeekOldest oldest = 2;
        SeekSpecified specified = 3;
    }
}

// SeekInfo specifies the range of requested blocks to return
// If the start position is not found, an error is immediately returned
// Otherwise, blocks are returned until a missing block is encountered, then behavior is dictated
// by the SeekBehavior specified.  If BLOCK_UNTIL_READY is specified, the reply will block until
// the requested blocks are available, if FAIL_IF_NOT_READY is specified, the reply will return an
// error indicating that the block is not found.  To request that all blocks be returned indefinitely
// as they are created, behavior should be set to BLOCK_UNTIL_READY and the stop should be set to
// specified with a number of MAX_UINT64
message SeekInfo {
    enum SeekBehavior {
        BLOCK_UNTIL_READY = 0;
        FAIL_IF_NOT_READY = 1;
    }
    SeekPosition start = 1;    // The position to start the deliver from
    SeekPosition stop = 2;     // The position to stop the deliver
    SeekBehavior behavior = 3; // The behavior when a missing block is encountered
}

message DeliverResponse {
    oneof Type {
        common.Status status = 1;
        common.Block block = 2;
    }
}

service AtomicBroadcast {
    // broadcast receives a reply of Acknowledgement for each common.Envelope in order, indicating success or type of failure
    rpc Broadcast(stream common.Envelope) returns (stream BroadcastResponse) {}

    // deliver first requires an Envelope of type DELIVER_SEEK_INFO with Payload data as a mashaled SeekInfo message, then a stream of block replies is received.
    rpc Deliver(stream common.Envelope) returns (stream DeliverResponse) {}
}
```